# Position background image exactly halfway into screen

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the best way to position an image so that it hangs into the screen exactly at the image's halfway point.

I have looked around and found various things about positioning within a div, but not within the entire screen.

I have tried `position: absolute;`, `background-position` and other css styles.

Using percentages does not work properly as when the screen is resized, the image moves left/right and is not fixed on its vertical axis.

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/december-holidays-days-2-30-6753651837108830.3-law.gif');
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me is to set the background element to `position:fixed` and then set the width to 200%. This always keeps the image exactly halfway in the screen no matter what width the screen is.

```css
.background {
  position: fixed;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url('https://marketing.dcassetcdn.com/blog/30-Famous-Triangle-Logos/google-drive-logo.jpeg');
  height: 75%;
  width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Common Solution**

`margin: 0 auto;` is the most common and simple solution for centering a `div` in the screen or its parent. `margin: 0 auto;` is shorthand to set the top and bottom margins to zero and the left and right margins to auto.

```css
.background {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/december-holidays-days-2-30-6753651837108830.3-law.gif');
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</body>
```

**Fixed Solution (Not recommended)**

If your div that want to centering has fixed with and height you can manage it with positioning absolutely.

```css
#center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #111314;
}
```

```html
<div id='center'></div>
```

**Another Solution**

Flexbox, is the great method. It's responsive but you have to set its parent as a `flex` with display property. `justify-content: center;` will center its childrens horizontally and `align-items: center;` vertically.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  background-color: #112341;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you used `background` so you can't get what you want.

So here as i do it :

CSS & HTML:

```css
    .background {

      width: 50%;
      margin-right: 25%;
      float: right;
      height: 500px;
      text-align: center;;

    }
    img{
        width: 100%
    }
```

```html
<html>

    <body>
      <div class="background">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/december-holidays-days-2-30-6753651837108830.3-law.gif">
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```